# Using a ScrollViewer with an ItemsControl with a Canvas as the ItemsPanel

Tags: wpf, canvas, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I have an ItemsControl and I set the ItemsPanel to a Canvas. The Canvas needs to be able to dynamically size with the content I put in it, and I need to be able to scroll when content runs off the bounds of the control. The trouble is I can't get the content to scroll. I have the scroll bar visibilities set to auto, so I don't end up seeing the scroll bars pop up when content runs off the edge.

I tried both putting the ItemsControl inside a ScrollViewer, and I tried using a ScrollViewer in the ItemsControl's Template.

Here's the ItemsControl inside the ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
            ...
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And here it is with the ScrollViewer in the Template:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tiles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ItemsControl>
```

[This post on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/949c9b3d-eaf2-40d0-bf88-c334c12e175a/itemscontrol-and-scrollviewer?forum=wpf) seemed promising, but implementing it on my code, or even explicitly with a Canvas in lieu of a WrapPanel wasn't working (or, should I say, I wasn't able to get it to work).

I've also taken a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852376/wpf-programatically-scrolling-a-canvas-in-a-items-control) but the solution doesn't work for me as I need the canvas to be able to size with the content (otherwise the scroll bars are always visible).

Thank you kindly, in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canvas's width/height when not explicitly set, will inherit from the `ItemsControl`.  The "dynamic sizing" behavior you're expecting isn't how panels sizing and layout works out of the box.

You options are to:

1. Explicitly set the `ItemsControl` Width/Height.
2. Explicitly set the Canvas Width/Height.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was fearing. Perhaps it would work if I calculated the size of the contents of the canvas as I add them, and update the width/height that way?

Edit: Yes indeed, it works as I need. Thanks for helping sort this out, Michael!